# Min Path Sum in Matrix- Brute Force

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, matrix

I'm working on the following problem:

> Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.
>    Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

My initial impression here was to, from each position in the grid, get the min length of going to the right vs going downward. However, this gives me the incorrect answer for the following:

```
Input:
[[1,2],[1,1]]
Output:
2
Expected:
3
```

Intuitively, not sure what I'm doing wrong. It's also very simple code (I know it's not memoized--was planning on that for the next step) but intuitively not sure what's going wrong. The recursive base case makes sense, and each number is being taken into consideration.

```
def min_path_sum(grid)
    smallest_path(0, 0, grid)
end

def smallest_path(row, col, grid)
    return 0 if (row == grid.length || col == grid.first.length)
    current_val = grid[row][col]
    [current_val + smallest_path(row+1, col, grid), current_val + smallest_path(row, col+1, grid)].min #memoize here

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make a proper termination condition.  You check only until you hit *either* the right column or bottom row.  You need to stay within bounds, but continue until you hit the lower-right corner.  You need to recur within bounds until you hit *both* limits.

Given that, your code does work okay: it finds the path of 2 to the bottom row, rather than the path of 3 to the right edge.  You just have to teach it to finish the job.

Is that enough to move you to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a shortest path problem on an acyclic directed graph, you could use a standard [shortest path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

You could also use dynamic programming ("DP), which may be the most efficient optimization technique. My answer implements a DP algorithm.

A shortest-path or DP algorithm would be vastly superior to enumerating all paths from top-left to bottom-right. As the number of paths increases exponentially with the size of the array, simple enumeration could only be used on modest-sized arrays.

The idea of the DP algorithm is as follows. Let `n` and `m` be the numbers of rows and columns, respectively. First compute the shortest path from each column in the last row to the last column in the last row. This is an easy calculation because there is only one path to `[m-1, n-1]` for each of these elements. Starting with `[m-1, n-2]` we simply work back to `[m-1, 0]`.

Next we compute the shortest paths from each element in each of the other rows to `[m-1, n-1]`, starting with the penultimate row (`m-2`) and working back to the first row (`0`). The last element in each row, `[i, n-1]`, is an easy calculation because one can only go down (to `[i+1, n-1]`). Therefore, the shortest path from  `[i, n-1]` to `[m-1, n-1]` is first going to `[i+1, n-1]` and then following the shortest path from `[i+1, n-1]`, which we've already computed (including its length, of course). The length of the shortest path from `[i, n-1]` is the "down" distance for `[i, n-1]` plus the length of the shortest path from `[i+1, n-1]`.

For elements `[i, j]`, n-1`,`i < `j < m-1`, we calculate the shortest paths if we go right and down, and select the shorter of the two.

We can implement this as follows.

**Code**

```
def shortest_path(distance)
  last_row, last_col = distance.size-1, distance.first.size-1
  h = {}
  last_row.downto(0) do |i|
    last_col.downto(0) do |j|
       h_right = { min_path_len: distance[i][j][:r] + h[[i,j+1]][:min_path_len],
                   next_node: [i,j+1] } if j < last_col
       h_down  = { min_path_len: distance[i][j][:d] + h[[i+1,j]][:min_path_len],
                   next_node: [i+1,j] } if i < last_row
       g =
       case
       when i == last_row && j == last_col  
         { min_path_len: 0, next_node: nil }
       when i == last_row
         h_right
       when j == last_col
         h_down
       else
         [h_right, h_down].min_by { |f| f[:min_path_len] }
       end
       h[[i,j]] = g
    end
  end
  build_path(h)
end

def build_path(h)
  node = [0, 0]
  len = h[node][:min_path_len]
  arr = []
  while h[node][:next_node]
    arr << node
    node = h[node][:next_node]
  end
  [len, arr]
end
```

**Example**

Suppose these are the distances between adjacent nodes.

```
● 4 ● 3 ● 1 ● 2 ●
6   2   5   4   5
● 3 ● 4 ● 6 ● 3 ●
1   3   4   2   3
● 6 ● 3 ● 1 ● 2 ●
```

It's convenient to provide this information in the form of an array of hashes.

```
distance = [
  [{ r: 4, d: 6 }, { r: 3, d: 2 }, { r: 1, d: 5 }, { r: 2, d: 4 }, { d: 5 }],
  [{ r: 3, d: 1 }, { r: 4, d: 3 }, { r: 6, d: 4 }, { r: 3, d: 2 }, { d: 3 }],
  [{ r: 6  },      { r: 3 },       { r: 1 },       { r: 2 }]
]
```

We may now compute a shortest path.

```
p shortest_path distance 
  #=> [15, [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]]
```

A shortest path is given by the second element of the array that is returned. `15` is the length of that path.